# Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JSON crossdomain communication with PHP file and a local javascript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184207/json-crossdomain-communication-with-php-file-and-a-local-javascript-file)

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET","http://api.productwiki.com/connect/api.aspxop=search&q=iphone&format=json&ke y=123456789");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function (){
    if(xhr.readyState=== 4 && xhr.status==200){
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
}
xhr.send();
```

I am trying Ajax request to get data from the following Url. I go error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.productwiki.com/connect/api.aspx?op=search&q=iphone&format=xml&key=123456789. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Answer (score 0):

You're requesting from a different origin, you have to use JSONP.  JSONP allows you to pass the response from the server to a callback function in javascript.  The easiest way is to use jQuery and use the getJson() or ajax() methods, it'll allow you to do something like this:

```
$.getJSON('http://api.productwiki.com/connect/api.aspx?op=search&q=iphone&format=xml&key=123456789',
      yourCallback);
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked and answered a zillion times.  See here for one of those answers: [JSON crossdomain communication with PHP file and a local javascript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184207/json-crossdomain-communication-with-php-file-and-a-local-javascript-file/7184401#7184401).  The Google search phrase you want is "same origin policy" to find many other explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the webservice does not supports [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) which is needed to bypass the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

The product wiki [webservice api](http://connect.productwiki.com/connect-api/) supports JSONP so you can use that.

It requires you to set the `format=json` in the querystring. And it requires you to set a callback.

```
//callback function
function YourGlobalFunction( data ){
    console.log(data);

}

//Fetch the content with JSONP
var scr = document.createElement("script");
scr.src = "http://api.productwiki.com/connect/api.aspx?op=search&q=iphone&format=xml&key=123456789&format=json&callback=YourGlobalFunction";
document.body.appendChild(scr);
```

If you want to go simple and can use a library such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), it will handle setting the callback for you.

```
jQuery.getJSON(
    "http://api.productwiki.com/connect/api.aspx?op=search&q=iphone&format=xml&key=123456789&format=json",
    {}, 
    function(data){ 
        console.log(data);
    }
);
```