# Unable to retrieve data from cross domain JSON service URL using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JQuery won't get json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281039/jquery-wont-get-json)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = "http://local.yahooapis.com/LocalSearchService/V3/localSearch?appid=YahooDemo&query=pizza&zip=10504&results=2&output=json&callback=?";
    jQuery.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
    var url1 = "http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Products?$format=json&callback=?";
    jQuery.getJSON(url1, function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
</script>
```

By running the above code I am able to see first alert but not second. Can someone let me know the mistake over here ? The error I am receiving is "invalid label" in FF & expected ; in IE 8

Comment: I have placed the above code in a sample html file in my machine. I am trying to learn JSONP.

Answer (score 5):

The quest is actually using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), which is what [jQuery uses in the secret](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) when it detects a parameter in the URL called `callback`.

Go to the url [http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Products?$format=json&callback=xyzaxa](http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Products?%24format=json&callback=xyzaxa)  and notice that the content doesnt contain the string `xyzaxa`, this means that a callback is never called from the service.

Either you are using a wrong URL, or odata doesent support JSONP