# The simplest (or at least the one functional) way to init JSON obejct from URL (Geocoding API)

Tags: json, google-maps, google-geocoding-api

Im trying to geocode in my javascript code against Geocoding API. I get url defined
   `var url = "http://http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=New York, Manhattan&sensor=false"`

from which I need to retrive a JSON object. First approach I used was according to Wikipedia using XmlHttpRequest like this

```
var my_JSON_object = {};
var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
http_request.open("GET", url, true);
http_request.onreadystatechange = function () {
  var done = 4, ok = 200;
  if (http_request.readyState == done && http_request.status == ok) {
       my_JSON_object = JSON.parse(http_request.responseText);
  }
};
```

I run the code and get such output in debugger after open() function was triggered:

```
http_request: XMLHttpRequest
onabort: null
onerror: null
onload: null
onloadend: null
onloadstart: null
onprogress: null
onreadystatechange: function () {
readyState: 1
response: ""
responseText: ""
responseType: ""
responseXML: null
status: [Exception: DOMException]
statusText: [Exception: DOMException]
upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload
withCredentials: false
__proto__: XMLHttpRequest
```

which means that nothing really useful obviously happened. 
My second approach was due to json.org, Ive tried to make a get call with JSONRequest

```
var requestNumber = JSONRequest.get(
url, 
function (requestNumber, value, exception) {
    if (value) {
        document.write(value);
    } else {
        document.write(exception);
    }
}
```

Debugger told me that JSONRequest is not defined! Due to json.org its native JS object so whats the problem?
Just to notice, i use properly gained API key from google in the script nearby.

Explanation why my solution failed and any suggestion how to comply with this task would be much appreciated!

Comment: This is probably just a typo, but you have "http://" twice at the beginning of your url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read about hacks like [cross domain XHR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10375929/1325290) and [Apache/HTTP proxies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2921970/1325290) but the conclusion is that the [Javascript API V3 geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) is your only realistic option. This comment, [(from here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281039/jquery-wont-get-json) while not authoritative, shows that such JSON requests don't work anymore:

> One would reasonably expect the google maps api to allow cross domain
>   access, which it did until recently. Now it doesn't allow it any more;
>   i guess they allege security reasons but I also guess the real reason
>   is to oblige you to use only their code to get their service. So the
>   only way to get the data via javascript from the client is to use
>   Google's javascript api, which anyway gives you almost the same
>   flexibility as calling the api url directly.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921745/how-to-make-cross-domain-ajax-calls-to-google-maps-api) had the most useful information.