# trouble with example google maps code

Tags: google-maps-api-3

executing this:

```
$curl "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false"
```

returns this:

```
{
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

Why doesn't it work?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I get the same results when I hit that URL directly in the browser. It may have something to do with that being the sample address that is shown in [Geocoding Responses section of the Google Maps API Web Services Dev Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingResponses). Maybe they turned it off because it was getting overloaded?

I even tried a version of that address that has been URL encoded:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600%20Amphitheatre%20Parkway%2C%20Mountain%20View%2C%20CA&sensor=false

but get the same result as the original attempt.

I can tell you that if you go directly to http://maps.google.com/maps and key in: `1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA`, you *do* get results.

At any rate, your URL is basically formatted correctly and should work. Try a different address, formatted the same way, and you will get results. This worked fine for me:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Wrigley+Field&sensor=false

Some follow up, I'm not sure where you were trying to run your code, but if it was in a jsFiddle, you may be interested in this question: [JQuery won't get json?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5281039/1314132)

Comment: Did you really mean a place in Georgia, and not the baseball counterpart? :D I think this JSON service is unreliable and one should use the JavaScript API.

Comment: @HeitorChang Of course I meant the baseball reference :) but I was really just trying to verify that anything else would work. Agreed. I don't generally use the Web Services interface; I use JavaScript as well. But actually, I guess what I get back makes perfect sense; it is probably the closest valid _address_. I really should have used the PlacesLibrary for something like: `Wrigley Field`.